# angular -- accessing data of multiple http calls - how to resolve the promises

Tags: http, angularjs

I am getting stuck on something I think should be straight forward.  I need to take data from three different ajax calls, combine and process all three, and display the resulting array to the user.

In its simplest form my code looks like this:

```
function giftControler ($scope, $http) {
  var names = $http.get("names.json"),
      naughty = $http.get("naughty.json"),
      nice = $http.get("nice.json");
```

I understand that my variables are assigned to promises, not actual results, and that the http request have been passed to the event queue. If I follow these with executable statements these variables will be undefined. I don't understand how to wait for these promises to resolve in order to continue processing them.

What I would like to do is immediately add the code:

```
      for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++){
        for (var j=0; j<nice.length; j++){
          if (names[i] === nice[j]){
            names[i] = names[i] + "--Yay!!";
          };
        };
      };                
      $scope.kids = names;
```

The problem is that I can't just work off of the promises as if they were resolved arrays.  Javascript will see these for statements right after the http calls and try to execute them immediately, even though the promises have not been resolved.

Where I get stuck is that the [$http api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is giving me a promise object with three functions: `error`, `success` & `then`.  I am not sure what to do with that in this case. I need a single success function for all three.  I need all three to resolve, then process the data in each, and then assign the result to an angular model.

I am sure I am missing something obvious, but does anyone have a suggestion? In my real work I have several ajax calls multiple data sources and a lot of processing (comparing values, sorting, concatenating, etc) to come up with one good data collection, but I can't get passed this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You can use $q's function 'all':

```js
function giftControler ($scope, $http, $q) {
  var names = $http.get("names.json"),
      naughty = $http.get("naughty.json"),
      nice = $http.get("nice.json");
  $q.all([names, naughty,nice]).then(function(arrayOfResults) { 
      ... This callback would be called when all promised would be resolved
    });
```

This way is little bit cleaner.

Here is link to docementation: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have worked.  How you teased out this functionality from that incredibly sparse API documentation, I will never know. Maybe as Angular ramps up with their Google funding they can hire a technical writer to revamp their documentation.

Comment: Wow, I need make time to read that documentation more carefully. It makes everything simpler this way.

Comment: This is just like jQuery `$.when(<promises>).then(function(results) { // Finished promises cb here. });` So glad it exists for AngularJS!

Comment: Can i please ask - to help me understand how to pass info, would the arrayOfResults var contain [{names results},{naughty results},{nice results}]?

Comment: What happens if one call fails?

Comment: @Tropicalista See the docs. If any of the promises is resolved with a rejection, this resulting promise will be rejected with the same rejection value.

Comment: Worth noting here that in arrayOfResults, "each value corresponds to the promise at the same index/key in the promises array/hash"

Comment: how about if I want to have different $http get methods for different pages but they are using a single controller?