# angularjs: Can I combine this service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two JSON files that I need to load. I load them through separate services right now like below:

```
app.factory('AventosService', function($rootScope, $http)
{
  var data = [];
  return {
    promise: null,
    loadAventosJson: function()
    {
      this.promise = $http.get('resources/json/aventos.json',{timeout:20000}).then(
      function(response)
      {
        data = response.data;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('AventosJsonLoaded');
      },
      function(data)
      {
        log('ERROR: ' + data.status);
      })
    },
    getAventosJson: function()
    {
      if (!data.length && !this.promise) this.loadAventosJson();
      return data;
    }
  }
});

app.factory('PartsService', function($rootScope, $http)
{
  var data = [];
  return {
    promise: null,
    loadPartsJson: function()
    {
      this.promise = $http.get('resources/json/part_numbers.json',{timeout:20000}).then(
      function(response)
      {
        data = response.data;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('PartsJsonLoaded');
      },
      function(data)
      {
        log('ERROR: ' + data.status);
      })
    },
    getPartsJson: function()
    {
      if (!data.length && !this.promise) this.loadPartsJson();
      return data;
    }
  }
});
```

To call the service, I simply do a:

`$scope.aventosJson = AventosService.getAventosJson();`

and a

`$scope.partsJson = PartsService.getPartsJson();`

I then check if both events were fires. Both events being `AventosJsonLoaded` and `PartsJsonLoaded`

Comment: Can't you just copy the functions from one service into another?

Comment: I don't think so since I only have one promise

Comment: You can combine promises. Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545573/angular-accessing-data-of-multiple-http-calls-how-to-resolve-the-promises

Comment: @Bart that is more along the lines of what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
app.factory('TheService', function($rootScope, $http)
{
  var data = [];
  return {
    aventosPromise:null,
    loadAventosJson: function()
    {
      this.aventosPromise = $http.get('resources/json/aventos.json',{timeout:20000}).then(
      function(response)
      {
        data = response.data;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('AventosJsonLoaded');
      },
      function(data)
      {
        log('ERROR: ' + data.status);
      })
    },
    getAventosJson: function()
    {
      if (!data.length && !this.aventosPromise) this.loadAventosJson();
      return data;
    },
    partsPromise: null,
    loadPartsJson: function()
    {
      this.partsPromise = $http.get('resources/json/part_numbers.json',{timeout:20000}).then(
      function(response)
      {
        data = response.data;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('PartsJsonLoaded');
      },
      function(data)
      {
        log('ERROR: ' + data.status);
      })
    },
    getPartsJson: function()
    {
      if (!data.length && !this.partsPromise) this.loadPartsJson();
      return data;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: this was more along the lines of what I was going for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545573/angular-accessing-data-of-multiple-http-calls-how-to-resolve-the-promises but you are right, that is combining them. I didn't know you could have more than one promise like you showed