# How do I execute a function after all resources have resolved?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q, angular-resource

How do I delay execution of a function until *after* all of my `$resources` have resolved? My goal here is to be able to parse though the `log` array after all `$resources` have resolved and push a single success notification to the UI instead of pushing one notification per each success.

I've based my code below off of this question [angular -- accessing data of multiple http calls - how to resolve the promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14545573/1139787). I realize that `$scope.promises` is empty because `item.$save()` doesn't return anything but I hope you can see that I'm trying to push the unresolved promise to the `promises` array.

```
$scope.save = function () {
  $scope.promises = [];
  $scope.log = [];

  angular.forEach($scope.menuItems, function(item) {
    $scope.promises.push(item.$save(function(menu){
      debugger;                            // execution gets here 2nd
      console.debug("success");
      $scope.log.push(msg: 'success');
    }));
   }, this);

  $q.all($scope.promises).then(function() {
    debugger;                              // execution gets here 1st
    console.debug("all promises resolved");
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$save` does not return a promise, you will need an intermediate one:

```
  angular.forEach($scope.menuItems, function(item) {
    var d = $q.defer();   // <--- the intermediate promise
    item.$save(
      function(menu){
        debugger;
        console.debug("success");
        $scope.log.push(msg: 'success');
        d.resolve(menu);  // <--- resolving it, optionally with the value
      },
      function(error){
        d.reject(error);  // <--- rejecting it on error
      }
    );
    $scope.promises.push(d.promise);
   }, this);
```

By the way, do not forget to throw away the array of promises, or you will keep garbage:

```
$q.all($scope.promises).then(...).always(function() {
    $scope.promises = null;
});
```

And, if `$scope.promises` is *NOT* exposed to the view, it does not need to be in the scope; it can be just a var.

Comment: Thanks @nikos-paraskevopoulos, I'm trying your solution now.

Comment: Regarding `$scope` vs `var` in the iterator, here's why I thought I needed to assign to the `$scope` http://stackoverflow.com/q/19707213/1139787. Thanks.

Comment: Works great! Quick note, I'm using 1.1.4 and don't have `always()` yet  so I chained `then()` instead https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2424