# Unable to access local var in iterator

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was tricked into thinking I had to define local variables on the `$scope` (or `this` which is `$scope` inside the function) in order to access them inside the iterator. At the `debugger` statement, the `names` array is not accessible if I don't have a reference to it. But as soon as I uncomment the second debug statement, `names` is accessible.

Why does `names` become accessible only after I declare it? And is there a way to avoid this when debugging?

```
$scope.test = function() {
  var greeting = 'hello';
  var names = ['alice', 'bob', 'cathy'];
  var fruit = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'];

  angular.forEach(fruit, function(item, index) {
    debugger;                                    // greeting is on the closure; names is not
    console.debug(greeting + item);
    // console.debug(greeting + names[index]);   // if enabled, suddenly names is now on the closure also
  }, this);
}
```

Comment: If you don't reference a variable from the inner context, what would be the point of the engine keeping hold of it in the closure?

Comment: @JamesAllardice Yep, that answers my question exactly. Thanks for linking