# $http.get API in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to do an `ng-repeat` in AngularJS that pulls from the [uiFaces API](http://uifaces.com/api). This is my code at the moment. This `http.get` is wrapped inside my `.controller`:

```
$http.get('http://uifaces.com/api/v1/random').success(function(data){
      $scope.uifaces = data;
});
```

And I'm trying to repeat a list of faces with `ng-repeat`:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="face in uifaces">
      <h6>{{ face.username }}</h6>
      <img ng-src="{{ face.image_urls.normal }}">
  </li>
</ul>
```

But I just keep getting two blank list items. I'm very new to Angular and APIs so trying to wrap my head around why nothing is being returned. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you logging `data` before set it to an scope? Are 100% sure that you are receiving a response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data` provided by `/random` isn't a collection of multiple `face`s to `repeat` for. It's just a single `Object`.

```
{
    "username": "...",
    "image_urls": {
        "normal": "...",
        ...
    }
}
```

Though, as an object, you could access its properties directly.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>{{ uifaces.username }}</h6>
    <img ng-src="{{ uifaces.image_urls.normal }}">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or, if you want to use it as a collection to `repeat`, you'll have to define that part yourself:

```
// wrap `data` in an `Array` to `repeat`
$scope.uifaces = [ data ];
```

Comment: I see. So I take it there's no way to get a repeat directly from that API – is that right? Can I still use an `ng-repeat`to have say, a list of three usernames and images, or are you saying I have to write that part myself?

Comment: @realph [It doesn't appear `/random` has any options to provide more than a single user](http://uifaces.com/api). You may try asking the owners if they'll add such an option. Otherwise, if you want a list of 3, you'll have to make 3 separate `$http.get()` requests and consolidate their individual `data`. Related: [accessing data of multiple http calls - how to resolve the promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545573/angular-accessing-data-of-multiple-http-calls-how-to-resolve-the-promises)

Comment: Would that be the most elegant way to do it? My sole purpose of using uiFaces is to generate a bunch of placeholder (but pretty) usernames and user pics for comment sections throughout my Angular app. So I need an easy way to pull usernames and pics for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result I got from that api call:

```
{
  "username": "jckieangel",
  "image_urls": {
    "epic": "https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/uifaces\/faces\/twitter\/jckieangel\/128.jpg",
    "bigger": "https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/uifaces\/faces\/twitter\/jckieangel\/73.jpg",
    "normal": "https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/uifaces\/faces\/twitter\/jckieangel\/48.jpg",
    "mini": "https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/uifaces\/faces\/twitter\/jckieangel\/24.jpg"
  }
}
```

So not sure why you are getting two blank LIs and not just one.

You'll need to strip out those backslashes in the image_urls before they will display right, so you'll probably want to add a helper method for that

```
  <h6>{{ face.username }}</h6>
  <img ng-src="{{ fixUrl(face.image_urls.normal) }}">
```

and then create `fixUrl(url)` in your controller

Also you'll need to either directly make it an array (or add the data to an existing one) `$scope.uifaces = [data];` or remove the `ng-repeat` since its a single item.

Answer (score 0):

don't use ng-repeat because its only one item.

```
<ul>
<h6>{{ face.username }}</h6>
      <img ng-src="{{ face.image_urls.normal }}">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="face in uifaces">
   <h6>{{ face.username }}</h6>
   <img ng-src="face.image_urls.normal">
  </li>
</ul>
```