# Asynchronous angularJS - how to wait each request callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm  building an angular application, there are many ajax calls.
I need to wait for each call response to get data from it, that why I make the 
synchronous.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: servicePath,
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    data: "{}",
    success: success,
    error: error
});
```

But this is a problem because if I call "showPleaseWait()"(this is a loading popup) it is not showing, because DOM is not updating unless ajax call is not complete.
It's showing if I'll make my call async, but I can't get my data that time.

Please, can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Solve your problem by learning how to manage callbacks instead of using (deprecated) synchronous requests.

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular -- accessing data of multiple http calls - how to resolve the promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545573/angular-accessing-data-of-multiple-http-calls-how-to-resolve-the-promises)

Comment: Call `showPleaseWait()` before `$.ajax`, and call `hidePleaseWait()` in the `success` or `error` callback. Async is the power of Ajax, why not?

Answer (score 0):

If you build a angular app you should take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http or https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

If you need to make the ajax calls one after another you can take a look at chaining promises

```
var a = $http.get('/your-url');
var b = a.then(function(result) {
     // use the results here ...
     return $http.get('/your-other-url');
});
b.then(function(result) {
    // use the results here ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not uncommon for Angular beginners to be thoroughly confused, however you are going wrong in two places. I would recommend some studying.  Without encouraging spoon-feeding, here are some good places two start.

1. You need to read about what's the right way to make ajax data calls in angular. Here's a good place to start :(https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#data-services)
2. Use of JavaScript promises in Angular (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#return-a-promise-from-data-calls) .

All this because you did say you want to use angular.However, lookup [how you can use promises](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/) with $ajax function in jQuery

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try to call your showPleaseWait() function, then the [$scope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) from angular right before to send the ajax request? It should force angular to refresh the display.