# Fire callback after two separate successful http requests

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Root component of my application on init call two asynchronous functions from my services to get data. I would like to know how to call a function after they are both completed. I am using angular 2.0.0-alpha.44 and typescript 1.7.3

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/angular2';

import {ServiceA} from './services/A';
import {ServiceB} from './services/B';


@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<h1>Hello</h1>`
})
export class App {
  constructor(
    public serviceA: ServiceA,
    public serviceB: ServiceB
  ) { }

  onInit() {

    // How to run a callback, after 
    // both getDataA and getDataB are completed?
    // I am looing for something similar to jQuery $.when()
    this.serviceA.getDataA();
    this.serviceB.getDataB();
  }
}
```

`serviceA.getDataA` and `serviceA.getDataB` are simple http get functions:

```
// Part of serviceA
getDataA() {
  this.http.get('./some/data.json')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        // save res to variable
        this.data = data;
      },
      error => console.log(error),
      // The callback here will run after only one 
      // function is completed. Not what I am looking for.
      () => console.log('Completed')
    );
}
```

Comment: Maybe `$q.all` would help. Here's a [nice answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545573/angular-accessing-data-of-multiple-http-calls-how-to-resolve-the-promises).

Comment: Use [RxJS#forkJoin](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple still parallel solution would be something like:

```
let serviceStatus = { aDone: false, bDone: false };

 let getDataA = (callback: () => void) => {
     // do whatver.. 
     callback();
 }

 let getDataB = (callback: () => void) => {
     // do whatver.. 
     callback();
 }

 let bothDone = () => { console.log("A and B are done!");

 let checkServiceStatus = () => {

     if ((serviceStatus.aDone && serviceStatus.bDone) == true)
        bothDone();
 }

 getDataA(() => { 
     serviceStatus.aDone = true;
     checkServiceStatus(); 
});

getDataA(() => { 
     serviceStatus.bDone = true;
     checkServiceStatus(); 
});
```

I personally use [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) to get me out of sticky situations like this, might be worth looking at.

EDIT:

Given feedback that RxJS is actually being used:

```
let observable1: Rx.Observable<something>;
let observable2: Rx.Observable<something>;

let combinedObservable = Rx.Observable
    .zip(
        observable1.take(1), 
        observable2.take(1),
        (result1, result2) => {
            // you can return whatever you want here
            return { result1, result2 };
        });

combinedObservable
    .subscribe(combinedResult => {
        // here both observable1 and observable2 will be done.
    });
```

This example will run both observables in parallel and combine the result into one result when they are both done.

Comment: Angular2 uses RxJS (and the http-service returns an Observable). So the question would be better phrased "How to wait for multiple observables to complete?"

Comment: Ah i see, give me a sec.

Comment: Updated the answer with an example of how to do it with RxJS.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I was looking for. I only had to import RxJS like this: `import * as Rx from '@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/Rx'`

Answer (score 1):

You could pass getDataA and getDataB callbacks in their function definitions, then call whatever you want in order:

```
function getDataA(callback) {
     // do some stuff
     callback && callback();
}

function getDataB(callback) {
     // do some stuff
     callback && callback();
}

function toCallAfterBoth() {
    // do some stuff
}
getDataA(getDataB(toCallAfterBoth));
```

Comment: This works but it would lead to the services being run after each other rather than in parallel.

Comment: Why does that matter? Knowing that may help tailor a better answer.

Comment: If the services are called in parallel rather than synchronously the data will be downloaded from the server faster, and that is always a good thing. So therefore it is better to tun them in parallel.

Comment: Not necessarily - server is then running two processes at once which may delay response times. DB might have to make concurrent calls which delays responses. Bandwidth is then split in two for two concurrent requests which can slow down more than half in theory as well. Don't assume that concurrency == better just because.

Answer (score 0):

You could nest your function calls.

EG:

```
function getDataA (callback) {
    var dataA = {test:"Hello Data A"};
    callback && callback(dataA);
}

function getDataB (callback) {
    var dataB = {test:"Hello Data B"};
    callback && callback(dataB);
}

getDataA(function (dataA) {
    getDataB(function (dataB) {
        console.log("Both functions are complete and you have data:");
        console.log(dataA);
        console.log(dataB);
    });
});
```