# Merge two SCOPES from separate sources (same construct)

Tags: angularjs, merge, angularjs-scope, remote-server

I have a function

```
var getData = function() {
    $http.get('(url of remote site)/swi/20?expand=true').success(function (data) {
        $scope.listOfServices = data.runningServices;
    });
};
```

Which updates every 30 seconds and pulls of a list of services.

HOWEVER i would like to expand this to also pull from

```
$http.get('(url of remote site)/**pad**/20?expand=true')
```

and $

```
http.get('(url of remote site)/**bri**/20?expand=true')
```

for example and then MERGE the rusults (all in exactly the same format) into ONE $scope

How can I merge these HTTP gets with three different endpoints in the URL?

EDIT: Following the link in the first comment I have come up with THIS

```
var getData = function() {
        var swindon = $http.get('(url)/swi/10?expand=true'),
            paddington = $http.get('(url)/pad/10?expand=true'),
            reading = $http.get('(url)/rdg/10?expand=true');
        $q.all([swindon,paddington,reading]).then(function(arrayOfResults) {
            $scope.listOfServices = arrayOfResults;
            console.log($scope.listOfServices);
        });
    };

  getData();
```

but the problem is now is that I have an array of arrays that I simply cannot access in any way. I have even done a repeat within a repeat

Here is a screenshot of Google COnsole with the logged scope

[image]

I normally loop over the listOfServices.trainServices

FINAL EDIT:

Got it, used the loop within a loop properly i.e

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in listOfServices">
      <tr ng-repeat="service in item.data.trainServices">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest the calls, like this:

```
$scope.listOfServices = [];
$http.get('(url of remote site)/swi/20?expand=true')
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.listOfServices.concat(data.runningServices);

  $http.get('(url of remote site)/pad/20?expand=true')
  .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.listOfServices.concat(data.runningServices);

    //nest Another and so on...
    //$http.get('(url of remote site)/bri/20?expand=true')..
  });

})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {$scope.listOfServices = [];});
```

Or use a resolved promises as in the answer below:

[angular -- accessing data of multiple http calls - how to resolve the promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545573/angular-accessing-data-of-multiple-http-calls-how-to-resolve-the-promises)